# Android Web View

Tags: android

I am working on an android app that displays Web Content that it obtains from a Web site. The app obtains this content from a Web page. The problem is I want to display a particular portion of the Web page, not the whole thing as the whole thing contains excess unwanted content. How can I display the data I need?

Comment: *How can I display the data I need?* ... you need to hide unwanted content ...

Answer (score 0):

you need to download `HTML` code without `WebView` first. Then process it removing unwanted data, and then load resulting `HTML` into `WebView`

Comment: well, it is possible to hide or remove element from javascript called from native java code ... also it is easy to find such solution with simple googling

Comment: @Selvin, that's not me who needs this solution. I know that, but I prefer the way I described. If you want to provide a solution - use "Answer"